# Can't plot ellipse without fillcolor

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, ellipse

I really can't get this and I need to superimpose an ellipse onto an image. The problem is plotting the ellipse with the matplotlib.patches, but ending up with either a white graph or a filled ellipse. The code is very primitive and I'm not sure what to do, since I've never worked with this part of the matplotlib library.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.random as rnd
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse


ells = [Ellipse(xy=[0,0], width=30, height=10, angle=0,edgecolor='b', lw=4)]

fig = plt.figure(0)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
for e in ells:
    ax.add_artist(e)
    e.set_alpha(1)
    e.set_facecolor(none) #obvious mistake, but no idea what to do

ax.set_xlim(-100, 100)
ax.set_ylim(-100, 100)

plt.show()
```

I tried looking up the matplotlib.patches page, but there is no clear info on how to plot an ellipse, just the function in use.

Comment: Try capitalizing the N in None, it should work that way.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - That will result in the default blue color being used for the facecolor (the current behavior).  To specify no color in matplotlib, use the string `'none'`.

Comment: Learned something new. Either way, OP was on right track, just a character or two off.

Comment: `e.set_fill(False)` If the goal was a "unfilled" elipse

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, to specify no color for an argument in matplotlib, use the string `'none'`.  This applies equally for edge colors, face colors, etc.

In your case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.axis('equal')
ell = Ellipse(xy=[0,0], width=30, height=10, angle=0,
              edgecolor='b', lw=4, facecolor='none')

ax.add_artist(ell)
ax.set(xlim=[-100, 100], ylim=[-100, 100])

plt.show()
```

[image]

For fill specifically, you can also use `fill=False`, as @M4rtini notes in the comments. In matplotlib, using the `set(foo=bar)` or `set_foo(bar)` methods are typically identical to passing in the kwarg `foo=bar`. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.axis('equal')
ell = Ellipse(xy=[0,0], width=30, height=10, angle=0,
              edgecolor='b', lw=4, fill=False)

ax.add_artist(ell)
ax.set(xlim=[-100, 100], ylim=[-100, 100])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, worked perfectcly! I didn't think to put 'none' as a colour, instead of as a command.